# Convergence of $\sum \frac{i^n}{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}}$ (sanity check)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Is this just a direct application of Dirichlet's test?

Comment: Or even Leibniz to real and imaginary parts, but Dirichlet should work as well.

Comment: I'm considering the partial sums of $i^n$, rather than the $\ln$ part.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment when I realised it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. You may use the [Dirichlet test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test):
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}} \geq \frac1{\sqrt{\ln(n+2)}}, \quad n=1,2,\ldots,
\\\\
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{\sqrt{\ln(n+1)}} =0
\\\\
&\left|\sum_{n=0}^N i^n\right| =\left|\frac{1-i^{N+1}}{1-i}\right|\leq \frac2{\left|1-i\right|}
\end{align}
$$ giving the convergence of the initial series.